# Bootstrap Select Doesn't Work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select

I create form for a website using bootstrap framework and select type doesn't want to work.

My code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
              <label for="example-email-input" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Choose a style</label>
              <div class="col-xs-10"
                <select class="form-control" name="Style">
                    <option value="0" selected>All Paintings</option>
                    <option value="1">Featured</option>
                    <option value="2">Most popular</option>
                    <option value="3">Top rated</option>
                    <option value="4">Most commented</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

But in preview it looks like that:

[image]

All others bootstrap features work well :)

Comment: Might help to clarify how this differs from what you're expecting.  Is it safe to say you're expecting a dropdown which only shows a single option at a time?

Comment: Yeah. I'm looking for a dropdown thing to give it a name and using php connect to mysql  database :)

Answer (score 1):

you missed a **>** on the div col-xs-10

```
          <div class="col-xs-10" >
```